# Angular 5 json string rendering

Tags: angular

Am very new to Angular

I have this json string which i can see in my console log.

**{   "reservations":{     "hotelReservation":[       {         "propertyCode":"BAC",         "status":"Casino 7 Stars",         "expectedArrival":"2017-12-15T00:00:00-08:00",         "confirmationCode":"IJ87T",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-12-16T00:00:00-08:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"1",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"DD",         "roomTypeName":"2 Doubles smoking",         "wingName":"BT"       },       {         "propertyCode":"BAC",         "status":"Guaranteed",         "expectedArrival":"2017-12-22T00:00:00-08:00",         "confirmationCode":"LLY7T",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-12-23T00:00:00-08:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"1",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"DD",         "roomTypeName":"2 Doubles smoking",         "wingName":"BT"       },       {         "propertyCode":"CAC",         "status":"Casino 7 Stars",         "expectedArrival":"2017-09-19T00:00:00-07:00",         "confirmationCode":"RST4K",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-09-21T00:00:00-07:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"2",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"R2",         "roomTypeName":"Non Smoking Double Ocean View",         "wingName":"CT"       },       {         "propertyCode":"CAC",         "status":"Casino 7 Stars",         "expectedArrival":"2017-09-19T00:00:00-07:00",         "confirmationCode":"RIB2T",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-09-21T00:00:00-07:00",         "arrival":"2017-09-19T00:00:00-07:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"2",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"R2",         "roomTypeName":"Non Smoking Double Ocean View",         "wingName":"CT"       },       {         "propertyCode":"CAC",         "status":"Checked-Out",         "expectedArrival":"2017-07-11T00:00:00-07:00",         "confirmationCode":"VF99E",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-07-12T00:00:00-07:00",         "arrival":"2017-07-11T00:00:00-07:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"2",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"R2",         "roomTypeName":"Non Smoking Double Ocean View",         "wingName":"CT"       },       {         "propertyCode":"LAU",         "status":"Cancelled",         "expectedArrival":"2017-11-25T00:00:00-08:00",         "confirmationCode":"BRBJ5",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-11-26T00:00:00-08:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"1",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"G2",         "roomTypeName":"ACCSS 2BD N/S",         "wingName":"ST"       },       {         "propertyCode":"RLV",         "status":"Guaranteed",         "expectedArrival":"2017-10-23T00:00:00-07:00",         "confirmationCode":"TR56B",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-10-30T00:00:00-07:00",         "adults":"2",         "children":"0",         "nights":"7",         "adaAccessibleReq":"true",         "roomTypeCode":"L3",         "roomTypeName":"Queen Non Smoking Mountain View",         "wingName":"MT"       },       {         "propertyCode":"RLV",         "status":"In-House",         "expectedArrival":"2017-10-29T00:30:00-07:00",         "confirmationCode":"ZZT1E",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-11-02T00:30:00-07:00",         "arrival":"2017-10-29T12:30:00-07:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"4",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"C1",         "roomTypeName":"King non Smoking",         "wingName":"MT"       },       {         "propertyCode":"RLV",         "status":"Checked-Out",         "expectedArrival":"2017-08-22T00:00:00-07:00",         "confirmationCode":"AA5TH",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-08-23T00:00:00-07:00",         "arrival":"2017-08-22T00:00:00-07:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"1",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"C1",         "roomTypeName":"King non Smoking",         "wingName":"MT"       },       {         "propertyCode":"ILV",         "status":"Pre-Registered",         "expectedArrival":"2017-11-01T00:00:00-07:00",         "confirmationCode":"NH4RT",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-11-02T00:00:00-07:00",         "adults":"3",         "children":"0",         "nights":"1",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"D3",         "roomTypeName":"2 Queens Non Smoking/View",         "wingName":"CC"       },       {         "propertyCode":"ILV",         "status":"Guaranteed",         "expectedArrival":"2017-11-20T00:00:00-08:00",         "confirmationCode":"UN8HG",         "expectedDeparture":"2017-11-22T00:00:00-08:00",         "adults":"1",         "children":"0",         "nights":"2",         "adaAccessibleReq":"false",         "roomTypeCode":"D3",         "roomTypeName":"2 Queens Non Smoking/View",         "wingName":"CC"       }     ],     "restaurantReservation":[       {         "propertyCode":"CAC",         "status":"Created",         "expectedArrival":"2017-09-19T15:15:00-07:00",         "id":"RT85472528",         "location":"Nero's Tuscan Steakhouse - Caesars Atlantic City",         "confirmationCode":"RT85472528",         "partySize":"1",         "patronName":"MelissaMullin",         "phoneNumber":"9794524957"       },       {         "propertyCode":"CAC",         "status":"Created",         "expectedArrival":"2017-12-16T14:15:00-08:00",         "id":"RT85472537",         "location":"Nero's Tuscan Steakhouse - Caesars Atlantic City",         "confirmationCode":"RT85472537",         "partySize":"2",         "patronName":"MelissaMullin",         "phoneNumber":"9794524957"       },       {         "propertyCode":"CAC",         "status":"Created",         "expectedArrival":"2017-12-22T14:15:00-08:00",         "id":"RT85472589",         "location":"Nero's Tuscan Steakhouse - Caesars Atlantic City",         "confirmationCode":"RT85472589",         "partySize":"4",         "patronName":"MelissaMullin",         "phoneNumber":"9794524957"       },       {         "propertyCode":"LAS",         "status":"Created",         "expectedArrival":"2017-08-22T15:15:00-07:00",         "id":"RT85468971",         "location":"Ruth's Chris Steakhouse - Harrah's Las Vegas",         "confirmationCode":"RT85468971",         "partySize":"3",         "patronName":"MelissaMullin",         "phoneNumber":"9794524957"       },       {         "propertyCode":"LAS",         "status":"Created",         "expectedArrival":"2017-10-29T15:15:00-07:00",         "id":"RT85468998",         "location":"Ruth's Chris Steakhouse - Harrah's Las Vegas",         "confirmationCode":"RT85468998",         "partySize":"2",         "patronName":"MelissaMullin",         "phoneNumber":"9794524957"       },       {         "propertyCode":"LAS",         "status":"Created",         "expectedArrival":"2017-11-21T14:15:00-08:00",         "id":"RT85469005",         "location":"Ruth's Chris Steakhouse - Harrah's Las Vegas",         "confirmationCode":"RT85469005",         "partySize":"1",         "patronName":"MelissaMullin",         "phoneNumber":"9794524957"       },       {         "propertyCode":"LAS",         "status":"Arrived",         "expectedArrival":"2017-10-30T15:15:00-07:00",         "id":"RT85469150",         "location":"Ruth's Chris Steakhouse - Harrah's Las Vegas",         "confirmationCode":"RT85469150",         "partySize":"1",         "patronName":"MeliMull",         "phoneNumber":"9794524957"       }     ],     "eventReservation":[       {         "id":"ERes794628574"       },       {         "id":"44528"       },       {         "id":"44529"       },       {         "id":"ERes794629672"       },       {         "id":"68051"       },       {         "id":"68050"       }     ],     "voucherReservation":[       {         "propertyCode":"RLV",         "status":"Created",         "expectedRedemptionDate":"2017-10-25T00:00:00-07:00",         "id":"VR795285364",         "productName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "confimationCode":"VRTR795285364",         "createdDate":"2017-10-25T10:32:38-07:00",         "expirationDate":"2017-11-23T00:00:00-08:00",         "numberOfVouchers":"1",         "skuName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "skuDescription":"Rio All-Suite Hotel"       },       {         "propertyCode":"RLV",         "status":"Created",         "expectedRedemptionDate":"2017-10-25T00:00:00-07:00",         "id":"VR795286053",         "productName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "confimationCode":"VRTR795286053",         "createdDate":"2017-10-25T10:32:38-07:00",         "expirationDate":"2017-11-24T00:00:00-08:00",         "numberOfVouchers":"2",         "skuName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "skuDescription":"Rio All-Suite Hotel"       },       {         "propertyCode":"RLV",         "status":"Created",         "expectedRedemptionDate":"2017-09-20T00:00:00-07:00",         "id":"VR795286128",         "productName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "confimationCode":"VRTR795286128",         "createdDate":"2017-09-20T10:32:38-07:00",         "expirationDate":"2017-10-20T00:00:00-07:00",         "numberOfVouchers":"1",         "skuName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "skuDescription":"Rio All-Suite Hotel"       },       {         "propertyCode":"RLV",         "status":"Created",         "expectedRedemptionDate":"2017-07-11T00:00:00-07:00",         "id":"VR795286729",         "productName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "confimationCode":"VRTR795286729",         "createdDate":"2017-07-11T10:32:38-07:00",         "expirationDate":"2017-08-10T00:00:00-07:00",         "numberOfVouchers":"3",         "skuName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "skuDescription":"Rio All-Suite Hotel"       },       {         "propertyCode":"RLV",         "status":"Created",         "expectedRedemptionDate":"2017-11-21T00:00:00-08:00",         "id":"VR795286735",         "productName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "confimationCode":"VRTR795286735",         "createdDate":"2017-11-21T10:32:38-08:00",         "expirationDate":"2017-12-20T00:00:00-08:00",         "numberOfVouchers":"1",         "skuName":"Buffet of Buffets 24 Hour Pass",         "skuDescription":"Rio All-Suite Hotel"       }     ]   } }**

How do i use this to display on a simple html table or datatables ??

Comment: This is a very basic and fundamental concept. I suggest you go through the Angular Tour of Heroes Tutorial if you haven't already: https://angular.io/tutorial Also you can look at the Docs for how to properly display data https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: This is not what Angular solves itself. Meaning you need to create your own component with the table presentation. Use `*ngFor` to iterate over the json and do your own view..

Answer (score 0):

Convert the json string to json object using JSON.parse() and then use HTML tablet elements with ngFor on td elements.

`<tr ngFor = "let item of data">
<td> {{item.propertycode}}</td>
</tr>`

This should solve the issue.

Comment: I need to access hotelReservation array. how can i access this inside <td> tag??

Comment: here data is the array having the object reservations.hotelReservation
So assign the variable data = reservations.hotelReservation in your controller or component file depending on the version of angular you are using. And use that data as the model obejct in the html.

Comment: can you give a small example?? Am getting the whole response inside this.data. So how should i access hotelReservation??

Comment: If you are using angular1 -  this should help.
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_http_properties